# 湖在城市的北部 or 湖在城市的北边?

Tags: grammar

I wanted to say that the lake is in the northern part of the city. As 北部 means the northern part, I naturally thought that 湖在城市的北部 would be a correct way of putting it. But some people said that 湖在城市的北边 is the correct answer. As I know that 北边 can also be used to mean the northern part for architectural regions like campus, which also seems to apply to cities, now I am not so sure which one I have to use. Do I have to use 北边 or 北部?

#### EDIT

My question was more specific. 湖在城市的北部 would mean like that the lake is actually inside the city, but in the northern part of the city. 北边 means north, so I thought that saying 湖在城市的北边 would mean that the lake is to the north of the city, and outside the city. However, I learned that 北边 can also denote that something is inside a specific region if it is talking about an architectural region, which was why I was confused.

So in summary, I was asking if I have to use 北部 or 北边 in this sentence to mean that the lake is in the city, but in the northern part of the city.

Comment: is user aware of the great deal of relevant information available in online dictionaries, in particular usage examples?  bkrs:  **北部**  (1) [north]
(2) 在某一明指或隐含的定向点以北的地区或国家
(3) 泛指一地、 一国的北方地区，一地的北方区域。相对于南部而言。
如：「桃、竹、苗地区，位于台湾的北部区域。」城市北部
re Northern part of a city, submit  **城市北部**  to iciba:  很多大学在城市北部.同时,这片柳树林在这个城市北部能有效缓冲冷空气向城市蔓延.公园位于该城市的北部.(E at site)  **城市北边**  iciba：这一条街是通往此城市北边的要道.奥运场馆在城市的北边.我教授的家,在尾张旭市, 名古屋北边一点的一个城市.（confirming "part" and "side" correspond well to C usage)

Comment: (as in English) both are possible,  e.g. (in) Chicago Northside (a part of Chicago) (在）芝加哥北边, to the north of a place: 在某地方的北边

Comment: "北部" always "within the city", but "北边" can be "outside or" or "within", it only stresses 'near the border'.

Answer (score 7):

You are actually correct.

> I wanted to say that the lake is in the northern part of the city. As 北部 means the northern part, I naturally thought that 湖在城市的北部

城市的北边 is often considered outside of the city.

城市的北部 is often considered within the city.

I said **often**, so it's still possible that someone refers to *within the city* when they say 城市的北边 in a colloquial context. Sometimes, you have to check them again by asking *do you mean within or outside of the city?*.

My two cents. Hope it would help.

Answer (score 3):

When you write a serious article, like city planning, or when you say it in a formal situation, 北部 is more used. Example:

1. 中国的北部有辽阔的土地。
2. 这座城市的北部准备规划一个自然公园。

And in our daily life, 北边 is used more often. 北边 is more casual.
Example:

1. 学校的北边有家商店。
2. 快看！北边有架飞机飞过来了！

Answer (score 1):

那个湖在这个城市的北部。

你们中国人听到‘这个’或者‘那个’有什么区别马？

English has 'this (object close by)' 'that (object further away)

"that: From c. 1200 opposed to this as indicating something farther off.